# I can't add repository to argo cd

Tags: kubernetes, repository, argocd

> Unable to create application: application spec for sasasa is invalid:
> InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: repositories not
> accessible: &Repository{Repo:
> "https://gitlab.com/elshan24/DevOps.git", Type: "", Name: "", Project:
> ""}: repo client error while testing repository: rpc error: code =
> Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while
> dialing dial tcp: lookup myargocd-repo-server on 169.254.25.10:53:
> server misbehaving

I have installed argo cd in Kubernetes. I checked the network, DNS and repository, I don't see any problem. Ping too is working. But I can't add a repo to argo cd. Repository is public